# call_user_func with parent method in child method

Tags: php, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
class A {
    protected $v = 'a';

    public function f() {
        echo 'f in A: ('.get_class($this).', '.$this->v.')<br/>';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $v = 'b';
    public function f() {
        echo 'f in B: ('.get_class($this).', '.$this->v.')<br/>';
        call_user_func(array($this, 'parent::f'));
    }
}

class C extends B {
    protected $v = 'c';
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$c = new C();

$a->f();
$b->f();
$c->f();
```

My expected output is:

```
f in A: (A, a)

f in B: (B, b)
f in A: (B, b)

f in B: (C, c)
f in A: (C, c)
```

But what I get is an infinite loop at the end. After a bit of research, someone pointed to me that `call_user_function(array($this, 'parent::f'))` calls `B::f` when used in `C`.

From, there I found 3 options that work, but I do not know which one is the « good » way of doing it. **Which one of the three following methods is the « correct » way?**

```
// Option 1, explicit specification of the parent class
call_user_func(array($this, 'A::f')) ;
// Option 2, use of __CLASS__ instead of $this
call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, 'parent::f')) ;
// Option 3, combination of both options 1 and 2
call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, 'A::f')) ;
```

Comment: `call_user_func('parent::f');`

Comment: @Ja͢ck Wow, did not even though about this simple way... Thanks. Could you enlighen me on why `array($this, 'parent::f')` does not work while `'parent::f'` does? (Maybe in an answer so I'll be able to accept it).

Comment: btw: PHP supports `$fn='f'; parent::$fn()` (since version 5.x?) if that is your goal: keeping $fn dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly identified that this code:

```
call_user_func (array($this, 'parent::f'));
```

When run in the context of `C` will keep calling `B::f` because `$this` will always be an instance of `C` and the parent of `C` is always `B`.

To fix it you can simple do:

```
call_user_func('parent::f');
```

It has no reference to the calling class, so it will resolve the parent class properly.

Out of the working alternative you have provided, the following is the better one:

```
call_user_func (array(__CLASS__, 'parent::f'));
```

This is because `__CLASS__` always refers to the class declaration in which it appears and so will always be `B`.

Comment: I find `call_user_func('parent::f');` making an instance call as if `parent::f();` stood there literally a bit counter-intuitive  ...but that's proably just me ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK i hope you're not suggesting that only this aspect of php is counterintuitive ;-)

Comment: at least this is one of the more interesting items on the list :D